# How to terminate two process with tkinter button in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, multiprocessing

I want to create two processes with python script. There is need to start and stop those processes via tkinter button. Processes start correctly, but terminate not. Which simplest way to correctly terminate processes with tkinter button?
Which best-practice way?

```py
from tkinter import *
import multiprocessing

def print1():
    global a
    while a == True:
        print('im process 1')

def print2():
    global a
    while a == True:
        print('im process 2')

def start():
    process1.start()
    process2.start()

def stop():
    global a
    a = False

a = True

if __name__ == '__main__':

    process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = print1)
    process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = print2)

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Title")
    root.geometry("200x200")

    app = Frame(root)
    app.grid()

    start = Button(app, text="Start", command=start)
    stop = Button(app, text="Stop", command=stop)
    start.grid()
    stop.grid()
    root.mainloop()
    process1.join()
    process2.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be in the stop method.

I think I might know what the problem is, but I'm not 100% sure. The answer to why appears to be in the python documentation. This code here runs fine (I edited the syntax and used `tkk` for the buttons, it looks better):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import multiprocessing


def print1():
    global a
    while a is True:
        print('im process 1')


def print2():
    global a
    while a is True:
        print('im process 2')


def start():
    process1.start()
    process2.start()


def stop():
    process1.kill()
    process2.kill() 


a = True

if __name__ == '__main__':

    process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=print1)
    process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=print2)

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Title")
    root.geometry("200x200")

    app = Frame(root)
    app.grid()

    start = ttk.Button(app, text="Start", command=start)
    stop = ttk.Button(app, text="Stop", command=stop)
    start.grid(padx=15, pady=20)
    stop.grid(column=1, row=0)
    root.mainloop()
    process1.join()
    process2.join()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary variables are *not* shared between instances of a `multiprocessing.Process`.

This means your:

```
global a
```

is a *different* global variable in each process, separate from the *third* `global a` in your main Python program.  So when you use the tk button to set that last `a` to `False`, the `a` in the process remembered through `process1` is still `True`, as is the `a` in the process remembered through `process2`.

You *can* share variables across processes.  There are two ways to do that: via [`Manager` instances](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers), or via shared memory.  Shared memory is more efficient, but more difficult to use, and sometimes has OS dependencies, so if you don't need particularly high performance, consider using a Manager.